# Android java.util.hashmap cannot be cast to java.util.list

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-volley

I'm trying to retrieve data from a json with multiple values and cast it into a  listview but im gettting the error java.util.hashmap cannot be cast to java.util.list.

I'm using volley.

The FeedListActivity Class:

```
 public void updateList() {
        feedListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
        feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));
        feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = feedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ClientesContatosModel newsData = (ClientesContatosModel) o;

                Intent intent = new Intent(FeedListActivity.this, FeedDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nome", newsData);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
 JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");
            // parsing json object
            for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);

                feedList = new ArrayList<ClientesModel>();
                ClientesModel mClientesModel = new ClientesModel();
                ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatoModel = new ClientesContatosModel();

                /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto no modelo */
                mClientesModel.setId(item.optInt("id"));
                mClientesModel.setNome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClientesModel.setTipo_pessoa(item.optString("tipo_pessoa"));
                mClientesModel.setInformacoes_adicionais(item.optString("informacoes_adicionais"));
                mClientesModel.setCpf(item.optString("cpf"));
                mClientesModel.setCnpj(item.optString("cnpj"));
                JSONArray contatos = item.getJSONArray("contatos");
                for (int j = 0; j < contatos.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject data = contatos.getJSONObject(j);

                    mClientesContatoModel.setNome(data.optString("nome"));
                    mClientesContatoModel.setCargo(data.optString("cargo"));
```

FeedDetailsActivity class:

```
public class FeedDetailsActivity extends Activity {

    private ClientesContatosModel feed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed_details);

        feed = (ClientesContatosModel) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("nome");

        if (null != feed) {


            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(feed.getNome());


        }
    }
```

Here is the Log:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.javatechig.feedreader/com.javatechig.feedreader.FeedDetailsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.javatechig.feedreader.model.ClientesContatosModel
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.javatechig.feedreader.model.ClientesContatosModel
                at com.javatechig.feedreader.FeedDetailsActivity.onCreate(FeedDetailsActivity.java:26)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: where are u using hashmap? i can't see it from this piece of code..

Comment: @nafas I've edited the code, I'm not using Hashmap but I'm getting that error, I don't know how

Comment: technically json is a hashmap. so what I think it is that one/some of your jsonobject field are wrong.(e.g. you think its a string but its something else. try to print a log after every  ***mClientesModel.setX***

Comment: @nafas thank you for your help man, it is working now, the "id" field was a string.

Comment: Don't now why the question was downvoted, upvoted+

Comment: @nafas If you want answer the question I can vote you up and accept your answer. Thanks again

Comment: @WARpoluido It's ok mate. as long as problem is solved. maybe you can answer the problem and explain what the problem was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because HashMap#values() return a java.util.Collection and you cant cast Collection into ArrayList, thus you get ClassCastException.

where as in case of ArrayList(HashMap.values()) ArrayList constructor takes Collection as an argument. Thus you wont get ClassCastException when you pass HashMap.values() as an argument to ArrayList.

HashMap#values(): check the return type in the source, as ask yourself, can a java.util.Collection be casted into java.util.ArrayList ?? No

```
 public Collection<V> values() {
921         Collection<V> vs = values;
922         return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
923     }
```

ArrayList(Collection): check the argument type in the source. can a method whose argument is a super type accepts sub type ? Yes

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
151         elementData = c.toArray();
152         size = elementData.length; 
153         // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
154         if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
155             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
156     }
```